# Overwriting system installed on USB

Tags: windows

I have an OS on my USB already but I was wondering if it is possible to format the USB, and put on the new OS.
For example, I have windows 10 on my USB, but I want to delete it and put on the new Ubuntu or windows 7 or any other. Is this something that I can do?

Comment: What is your specific problem or question, your OS/Version used, what have you tried so far on your own?

Comment: I installed the Windows 10 OS on my USB, (bootable drive) , and now I want to remove it. So my question was if it is possible to format the USB and install a new OS on it so I can Install it on my PC , ok ?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Keep in mind that you will lose any data on your USB drive.

Comment: Format your USB an follow this tutorial: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: If you **clone** from an Ubuntu iso file to the USB drive, you can do that directly without preparing the drive. Some extracting tools need pre-formatting, and it is described in the documentation for each of those tools. If you want a standard storage device again, please see [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/post).

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite your USB drive with a new OS or data, and you can also reformat the USB. Keep in mind that installing a new OS on the USB drive or reformatting it will overwrite any data that is currently stored on the USB drive, so make sure to backup whatever you want to keep first.

Answer (score 0):

Just flash the USB like you've done when it was empty.